# Vue.js pass local loop variable to v-bind:style

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I loop through a list and would like to set a background image according to a property in this list.
But in `v-bind:stlye` the property isn't defined.

How can I pass it?

```
        <div class="content" v-bind:key="slide.id" v-for="slide in show.slides">
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="model"
                     :style="{ backgroundImage:
                        `url(${strapiUrl + slide.model_media.Media.url})` }">
                    <div class="title">{{slide.title}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is `strapiUrl` being defined? Also, you are probably better off abstracting that into a method.

Comment: strapiUrl is defined in data().

Comment: Maybe you should check your div nested structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is simply easier to abstract the entire style binding into a method. In your template, you can simply do this:

```
<div class="model" v-bind:style="modelStyle(slide)">
```

Then, in your component, create a `modelStyle()` method:

```
modelStyle: function(slide) {
  return {
    backgroundImage: url(`${this.strapiUrl}${slide.model_media.Media.url}`);
  };
}
```